# display rendering problem ( most text, images and window edges split into tiny lines )?

Tags: drivers, display

[image: Screenshot]

[image]

edit : I put Elementary os on my old pc and I first encountered this problem. Then I tried ubuntu 15.10 the problem still persisted. I tried this on 2 led monitors and both have the problem.

I have a built in Intel 82Q963/Q965 graphics and I tried installing their drivers but I got this message when it rebooted :

none of the selected modes were compatible with the possible modes: Trying modes for CRTC 63 CRTC 63: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1366x768@60Hz (pass 0) CRTC 63: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1366x768@60Hz (pass 1) Trying modes for CRTC 64 CRTC 64: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1366x768@60Hz (pass 0) [same msg](pass 1) Trying modes for CRTC 65 CRTC 65: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1366x768@60Hz (pass 0) [same msg](pass 1)

other data that might help:

[/var/log/Xorg.0.log](http://pastebin.com/0Sqzbm3N).

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:    wily
```

`lspci -nnk | grep -A2 VGA`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 82Q963/Q965 Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:2992] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2808]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Comment: We need more info. What is your graphics card? What drivers are you using? Desktop or laptop?

Comment: Sorry I was not allowed to post more than two images :http://i.stack.imgur.com/esByW.png . I just installed the OS I have no Idea about the drivers. No dedicated graphics card: intel 965gm x86/mmx/sse2 ; old 32 bit CPU using a cheap LED monitor.

Comment: I had strange issues with my Intel graphics until I installed the proprietary Intel driver. Check this link out for installing them on 16.04, if you are using that: https://allanbogh.com/2016/01/05/ubuntu-16-04-installing-the-intel-graphics-drivers-using-the-intel-graphics-installer-for-linux/

Comment: @willem.hill just tried that. When I restarted after installing the problem persisted and I got this error/message:

none of the selected modes were compatible with the possible modes:
Trying modes for CRTC 63
CRTC 63: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1366x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 63: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1366x768@60Hz (pass 1)
Trying modes for CRTC 64
CRTC 64: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1366x768@60Hz (pass 0)
[same msg](pass 1)
Trying modes for CRTC 65
CRTC 65: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1366x768@60Hz (pass 0)
[same msg](pass 1)

Comment: @DavidFoerster made the edits but log is @ http://pastebin.com/0Sqzbm3N which I could not post

Comment: Thanks for all the info. +1 I can't see anything odd in the log file. My best suggestion is to give Ubuntu 16.04 a try. You can start with a Live DVD/USB before deciding whether to upgrade the installation on your computer.

Comment: @davidfoerster I tried elementary OS before this and that showed the same issue but this issue was not present in Windows

Comment: Looks like you just missed the 85Mhz max on one of the 1366x768 modes, so try increasing the max to 86.  Probably need to edit the /etc/X11/xorg.conf file to do that.  Generate one if necessary.

Comment: @ubfan can i directly edit this line? [    25.139] (WW) EDID timing clock 85.50 exceeds claimed max 85MHz,...

or maybe there is a Gui that handle this. Can you point me in the right direction to know more about this?

Answer (score 0):

First thing to try is to drop to a lower resolution and see if the problem goes away.  You didn't mention at what resolution Windows is actually running, along with the refresh rate.  The dot/pixel clock is generated from other values, see
http://arachnoid.com/modelines/

```
 Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: xconfig, VertRefresh source: xconfig
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "CRT-0"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 55.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection
```

The above goes into the xorg.conf file, which you might have to generate.  Playing around with the monitor like this is dangerous, you can destroy the monitor, start fires, etc.  Best to drop to a lower resolution.

---

Or a lower refresh rate, 60Hz may be too high.  You never did say what the Windows refresh rate was -- match it and the resolution.

Comment: So, I tried lowering the resolution to the lowest available 800x600 but there was something amiss as that is 4:3 and my monitor was running 1366x768 (16:9) previously and both were fitting the screen( the lines were still present ). So I rebooted and got : 

Could not apply the stored configuration for monitors       :
Trying modes for CRTC 63 CRTC 63: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 800x600@60Hz (pass 0) .       

Another peculiar thing is I can never access any info about my edid:

Comment: Another peculiar thing is I can never access any info about my edid:

$ get-edid gave me : 

http://pastebin.com/raw/4yRAphaJ